# Android Location API using Google Play Services

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3

I use to implement location fonder using with Android developer tutorial "https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html".my application is running but didn't find the location.

it is break 
`@Override`

```
`public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {`
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_location_detected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}`
```

with here and show no_location_detect .please guild me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Go through this link.I have followed the same
http://www.kpbird.com/2013/06/fused-location-provider-example.html